# Relative XPath Help for HTML Tag

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to create a relative XPath selector statement for this  tag below:

```
<a class="bttn bttn--primary bttn--inline js-localizeButton" ><span class="bttn__content">Click Me</span></a>
```

but I can't seem to get it to match.  Here is what I've tried:

```
//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")][1]
```

which returns the inner `<span>` tag, but not the `<a>` tag which I'm looking to get.

I've tried using classes (and would like to know why they fail, if possible):

```
'//a[@class="bttn"]'
'//*[@class="bttn"]'
```

I've got a feeling it's a pretty simple thing, but I'm done spending hours fiddling around on it and could use some help.

Comment: Maybe try `//a[contains(@class,"bttn")]` as your class string contains more than `bttn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")][1]`
>
> which returns the inner `<span>` tag, but not the `<a>` tag which I'm looking to get.

Many ways...

"From here to my parent"

```
//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")][1]/..
```

"From here to my parent `a`"

```
//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")][1]/parent::a
```

"From here to my first `a` ancestor"

```
//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")][1]/ancestor::a[1]
```

"An `a` element having me as child"

```
//a[*[contains(text(),"Click Me")]][1]
```

"An `a` element having me as descendant"

```
//a[.//*[contains(text(),"Click Me")]][1]
```